# Any MS Office online alternatives to Access DB?

Tags: list, microsoft-access

I have an Access DB that I load with data weekly, sometimes daily. In this Access DB I've made many queries that allow me to do a lot of reporting, as well as ad-hoc analysis.

Recently I was asked to share this DB by colleagues, so they would be able to have their own Access with own queries linked to my Access DB that I refresh weekly/daily.

Our company uses Sharepoint environment, and my first decision was:

- to export the data from my Access DB to Sharepoint Lists;
- to have an Access DB on my computer that I will use to load new data;
- to let other people to link their local Access DBs with queries to this list.

The problem that I faced is that since my table has ~10 columns and ~700k rows, it seems like Sharepoint Lists have no such capacity to operate this. I simply can't export this to a SPList.

What can be a solution here, considering the fact that I am not a programmer and using Access DB it's just a way for me to automate reporting/routine. I did data normalization already and reduced amount of rows/columns as much as I could.